# Show element before the clicked one Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a lot on .meta-entity containers. I add Buttons with .after()

```
$(".entry-utility").after("<div class='show_meta'>Artikel Infos einblenden/ausblenden</div>");
```

Click on Button should show the .meta-entity container before this button.

have some an idea how can i select the "parent" object?

```
<div id="post-314" class="block_modal span-8">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/online-steuererklarung-fur-selbstandige-314" title="Permalink zu Online-Steuererklärung für Selbständige" rel="bookmark">Online-Steuererklärung für Selbständige</a></h2>
            <div class="modaltext">
                <div class="entry-summary">
                <p>Selbständige können ihre Steuererklärung online, kostenlos und anonym bei verschiedenen Anbietern in sicherem Umfeld direkt im Webbrowser erstellen. Die Übermittlung an das Finanzamt ist dann allerdings kostenpflichtig. Bei der Online-Steuererklärung kann ohne die Installation einer Software, betriebssystemunabhängig und mit ggf. mit dem Zugriff mehrerer User gearbeitet werden. <a class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/online-steuererklarung-fur-selbstandige-314" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">→</span></span></a></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
                <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author">Publiziert am</span> <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/online-steuererklarung-fur-selbstandige-314" title="08:34" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">10. September 2010</span></a> <span class="meta-sep">von</span> <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/author/admin/" title="Zeige alle Beiträge von admin">admin</a></span>          </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

            <div class="entry-utility" style="display: none; ">
                                    <span class="cat-links">
                        <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links">Veröffentlicht unter</span> <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/category/artikel" title="Alle Artikel in In unseren Artikeln werden Sie fündig ansehen" rel="category tag">In unseren Artikeln werden Sie fündig</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/category/artikel/steuern" title="Alle Artikel in Wenn der Fiskus wartet… ansehen" rel="category tag">Wenn der Fiskus wartet…</a>                    </span>
                    <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
                                                    <span class="tag-links">
                        <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">Verschlagwortet mit</span> <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/betriebssystem" rel="tag">Betriebssystem</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/einkommensteuer" rel="tag">Einkommensteuer</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/einkommensteuererklarung" rel="tag">Einkommensteuererklärung</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/internet" rel="tag">Internet</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/konz" rel="tag">Konz</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/online-steuererklarung" rel="tag">Online-Steuererklärung</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/software" rel="tag">Software</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/steuererklarung" rel="tag">Steuererklärung</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/steuererklarung-online" rel="tag">Steuererklärung online</a>, <a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/tag/steuerfuchs" rel="tag">Steuerfuchs</a>                   </span>
                    <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
                                <span class="comments-link"><a href="http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/online-steuererklarung-fur-selbstandige-314#respond" title="Kommentiere Online-Steuererklärung für Selbständige">Hinterlasse einen Kommentar</a></span>
                            </div><div class="show_meta ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Artikel Infos einblenden/ausblenden</span></div><!-- .entry-utility -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

to find here http://lvps83-169-35-114.dedicated.hosteurope.de/category/artikel

thx

Comment: can you include some html? I can't imagine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> have some an idea how can i select the
>   "parent" object?

```
$('.button').click(function(){ var parent = $('this').parent(); });
```

Comment: with parent() he hides all parent objects... I need parent last

Comment: @Fincha - [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) would return only one. you must have confused it with [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/). But still, including your html would help us figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().find('.entry-utility').toggle("fast");
```

i have found the solution :)